# JAX-RS @CookieParam value changes from a request to another

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, cookies, jax-rs

I'm trying to make a resource which adds products into a shopping cart. I'm trying to add a product to the shopping cart and save the shopping cart as JSON String in a cookie. (Here the Cart object has 2 fields, productId and quantity)

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateShoppingCart(@CookieParam(COOKIE_NAME) javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie cookie, Cart cart) {
    NewCookie newCookie = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (cookie !=null){
        try {
            List<Cart> shoppingCart = mapper.readValue(cookie.getValue(), new TypeReference<List<Cart>>() {
            });
            //the case where there is already something in the shopping cart
            //...
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(shoppingCart);
            newCookie = new NewCookie(COOKIE_NAME, jsonString,"/", "", "shopping-cart", MAX_AGE, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        List<Cart> carts = new ArrayList<>();
        carts.add(cart);
        try {
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(carts);
            newCookie = new NewCookie(COOKIE_NAME, jsonString,"/", "", "shopping-cart", MAX_AGE, false);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Response.ok(newCookie).cookie(newCookie).build();
}
```

The first time when I run this, the cookie is set correctly for example it sets the correct value: [{\"productId\":1,\"quantity\":2}] if I add a product with the id 1 and quantity 2.
The problem is that when I run this a second time the cookie received as CookieParam has an incorrect value, in this case [{\"productId\":1 . 
I'm testing this with Postman and sending a POST request with the JSON {"productId":1, "quantity":2} in the body. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies have to be put in the header, not the body. Something like:

```
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3
```

For postman refer to : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies

UPDATE: In my experience, postman sometimes does not send cookies. Try converting postman command to curl command (refer to: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets) then make sure curl command has the cookie either in the header or in -b parameter (Refer: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: But this is exactly what I'm doing in Response.ok(newCookie).cookie(newCookie).build(); . I'm setting the cookie with a JSON value in the code, not Postman. The JSON I'm building from the body object which is a Cart type object {"productId":1, "quantity":2})

Comment: You can see in Postman response cookie, if the cookie you are setting in code is coming back. But in the next request - you have to manually copy the cookie from the response to the request.

Comment: I can also see it in the "manage cookies" box as described in the link provided by you, I don't have to manually add it. In Postman I see the correct value in cookie. The problem is in the resource when I get the cookie with @CookieParam

Comment: In "Manage Cookies" I have something like this in the cookie:  shoppingCart=[{\"productId\":1,\"quantity\":2}]; path=/; domain=localhost; Expires=Thu, 01 Mar 2018 18:58:18 GMT;

Comment: Most likely Postman is not sending the cookie. Try to generate the cUrl command from Postman (see the link). cUrl is very reliable. We have had issues with Postman not sending cookies. https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

Comment: Tried the cUrl command and same thing. I do get some data in the CookieParam... but it's not the expected value. Instead of getting the cookie value as [{\"productId\":1,\"quantity\":2}] I get only [{\"productId\":1

Comment: curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/shop-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/shoppingCart/update \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: cfaa64b7-f9f4-1675-d2d1-4cb71552c5e2' \
  -d '{"productId":1, "quantity":2}'

Comment: In your curl, your are not passing cookie. -d is for post data. Cookie can be passed in header or by using -b. Refer to: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: you are right ("You can see in Postman response cookie, if the cookie you are setting in code is coming back. But in the next request - you have to manually copy the cookie from the response to the request"). This works.